# Javascript rolling banner w/fadeup

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

The Org post was removed because I went back to the drawing board and started over. My new code does everything I want but Im sure it could do more. I hope this helps other ppl :)

```
<head>
<script>
// Set the slideshow speed (in milliseconds)
var SlideShowSpeed = 3000;

// Set the duration of crossfade (in seconds)
var CrossFadeDuration = 3;

var Picture = new Array(); // don't change this
var Link = new Array(); // don't change this
var Left = new Array();
var Right = new Array();

Picture[1]  = '1.jpg';
Picture[2]  = '2.jpg';
Picture[3]  = '3.jpg';
Picture[4]  = '4.jpg';

Link[1]  = "This is a One";
Link[2]  = "This is a Two";
Link[3]  = "This is a Three";
Link[4]  = "This is a Four";

Left[1] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeLeftOne()'>Left 4</a>";
Left[2] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeLeftTwo()'>Left 1</a>";
Left[3] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeLeftThree()'>Left 2</a>";
Left[4] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeLeftFour()'>Left 3</a>";

Right[1] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeRightOne()'>Right 2</a>";
Right[2] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeRightTwo()'>Right 3</a>";
Right[3] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeRightThree()'>Right 4</a>";
Right[4] = "<a href='#' onmousedown='changeRightFour()'>Right 1</a>";

var tss;
var iss;
var jss = 1;
var pss = Picture.length-1;

var preLoad = new Array();
for (iss = 1; iss < pss+1; iss++){
preLoad[iss] = new Image();
preLoad[iss].src = Picture[iss];}

function runSlideShow(){
if (document.all){
document.images.PictureBox.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=2)";
document.images.PictureBox.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=CrossFadeDuration)";
document.images.PictureBox.filters.blendTrans.Apply();}
document.images.PictureBox.src = preLoad[jss].src;
if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById("CaptionBox").href= Link[jss];
if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML= Left[jss];
if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML= Right[jss];
if (document.all) document.images.PictureBox.filters.blendTrans.Play();
jss = jss + 1;
if (jss > (pss)) jss=1;
tss = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', SlideShowSpeed);
}
function resetTime() {
    window.clearTimeout(tss);
tss = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', SlideShowSpeed);
}

function changeLeftOne() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[4];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="4.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[4];
jss = 4;
resetTime();
}
function changeLeftTwo() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[1];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="1.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[1];
jss = 1;
resetTime();
}
function changeLeftThree() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[2];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="2.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[2];
jss = 2;
resetTime();
}
function changeLeftFour() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[3];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="3.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[3];
jss = 3;
resetTime();
}
function changeRightOne() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[2];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="2.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[2];
jss = 2;
resetTime();
}
function changeRightTwo() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[3];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="3.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[3];
jss = 3;
resetTime();
}
function changeRightThree() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[4];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="4.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[4];
jss = 4;
resetTime();
}
function changeRightFour() {
document.getElementById("LeftBox").innerHTML=Left[1];
document.getElementById("PictureBox").src="1.jpg";
document.getElementById("RightBox").innerHTML=Right[1];
jss = 1;
resetTime();
}

function stopTime() {
(window.clearTimeout(tss));
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="runSlideShow()" bgcolor="#FFFFFF;">
<div id="LeftBox"></div>
<a id="CaptionBox" href="T">
<div id="test2" onMouseOver="stopTime()" onMouseOut="resetTime()"> <img src="1.jpg" id="PictureBox" name="PictureBox" width="40" height="40"> </div>
</a>
<div id="RightBox"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, can I borrow that time machine? I'd like to visit 1996, too... Okay, being serious: I'd recommend finding a different starting point, that is truly awful code. (I feel free to say this because you said it wasn't yours.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As T. J. Crowder said, it hurts to look at that code, here's how the declarations should look:

```
var gImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'],
    gNumberOfImages = gImages.length,
    gLink = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com' ...],
    gNumberOfLinks = gLink.length;
```

Comment: Lets say I dont know enought to do a code re-do. If you have any idea how to get the links to populate in the reqired area it would be very helpfull.

Comment: I dont expect anyone to re-do my code for me but if its really that bad and there is a better way of doing it, i wont stop anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to explain all the things wrong with that code, but your main problem is that document.link.href is invalid. If you were to use that construct (which you shouldn't), it'd be document.links[0].href (assuming there were no other anchors with hrefs preceding that one). Instead, just assign an id to the anchor tag, e.g., (<a id='link'>) and use getElementById('link') to access it.

The other thing you should do is associate your images and their links. If I were starting from scratch, I'd do it in JSON, but given your code, you could use a two-dimensional array, e.g.:

```
var images = [
  ["1.jpg", "http://www.yahoo.com"],
  ["2.jpg", "http://www.google.com"],
  // etc.
];
```

It's cleaner and clearer than using two separate arrays, and it helps prevent counting errors. You can access the first image object by typing images[0]; images[0][0] gives you its file name, and images[0][1] gives you its href.

Then, I'd either merge the loadSlide() and loadLinks() functions, or I'd just put their functionality in the nextSlide() function since they do so little. Good luck.

Comment: Well I started over and now I have fully working code. It does 95% of everything I want, Just wish the cross fade would work in FF